# Stripe client_reference_id: null in checkout.session.completed

Tags: django, django-models, stripe-payments

I have a stripe pricing table on my front end to render the options available to customers. On my backend I am using Django to handle account creation if the payment was successful. As below this was created following a tutorial on TestDriven.io btw.

```
if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        print(session)
        # # Fetch all the required data from session
        client_reference_id = session.get('client_reference_id')
        stripe_customer_id = session.get('customer')
        stripe_subscription_id = session.get('subscription')

        # Get the user and create a new StripeCustomer
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
        StripeCustomer.objects.create(
            user=user,
            stripeCustomerId=stripe_customer_id,
            stripeSubscriptionId=stripe_subscription_id,
        )
```

I am getting the following error

```
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(apps.authentication.models.CustomUser.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist
```

So after some digging I have found that Stripe is not returning the client_reference_id to my backend, below is a printout of the session variable

```
"client_reference_id": null,
```

I believe this is why the account is not being found by Django, but I can't seem to figure out why Stripe isn't sending this information over or how to attach it to the response to my Web hook?

Comment: Can you share your code for how you are embedding your Pricing Table and how you are dynamically setting the client-reference-id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue albeit in different technology stack.

The solution is to pass the extra info you require as `metadata` parameter. [See Stripe docs on this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata).

So:

```py
Session.create(
  success_url="https://example.com/success",
  cancel_url="https://example.com/cancel",
  line_items=[
    ...
  ],
  metadata={
    'user_id': my_user_id,
  }
)
```

this metadata dict is to be passed onto `checkout.session.completed` webhook event.

So:

```py
if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
  session = event['data']['object']
  metadata = session['metadata']
  ..
  user_id = metadata.get('user_id')
  ..
  user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=user_id)
```

[The metadata param is attached to most Stripe objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata?lang=python).

However, the `checkout.session.expired` and `payment_intent.canceled` (and probably others?) don't pass the previously fulfilled metadata.

Comment: hello , i found useful your reply, cause none of the chatgpt or bard or bing are able to. but i am stuck on the session ID. can you tell howto retrieve the session?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was setting "ClientReferenceId" to a null value

```
var options = new SessionCreateOptions
{
    // some codes here
    PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
    {
        CaptureMethod = "manual"
    },
    ClientReferenceId = cart.OrderNumber, /// <== problem here
    // more code here
}
```

Above code is part of setup for creating the checkout session. Because I generate `OrderNumber` after payment successfully posted, I was passing an empty order to Stripe. That was the problem.